# Dimensionality in Isomap

Tags: machine-learning, feature-extraction

Given a D-dimensional data (D features), what is the maximum number of projections (d-dimensions) in Isomap?

Usually for PCA, LDA, you have the same number of possible components as the number of your features... In isomap it seems to be possible to have more (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that you input consists of N data vectors, each of which is D dimensional.

Isomap constructs a N x N matrix based on finding near-neighbors and then looking for paths between near neighbors to connect far away neighbors, then Isomap solves an eigenvalue problem on this N x N matrix to define the projections

So, IF you have more datavectors than you have dimensions in each datavector, THEN you may have more projections than you have data points.

An easy data set to explore this is:

create 100 points randomly on a circle in 2D.  Then N = 100, D = 2.

The Isomap projections and coefficients will be non-zero for the first 99 projections.